# How to create a reusable ajax function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous

I'm trying to create a function that makes an AJAX call to another server and uses the return data in a callback. I want to be able to call this multiple times to different urls and use the different responses in different functions.

At the moment it makes the 2 calls but the only retrieves the one dataset (battlefield). What am I missing?

If I only make one call (to Treehouse) it all works fine.

```
/*Tests to see if ajax is available then Creates an Ajax request. 
*Params: url - the api url
*        type - the type of request (get, post). Default is get
*        callback - function to process the ajax response
*/
function makeRequest(url, type, callback) {
type = typeof type !== 'undefined' ? type : 'GET';
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // Mozilla, Safari, ...
  httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else if (window.ActiveXObject) { // IE
  try {
    httpRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
  } 
  catch (e) {
    try {
      httpRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    } 
    catch (e) {}
  }
}

if (!httpRequest) {
  alert('Giving up :( Cannot create an XMLHTTP instance');
  return false;
}
httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
  try {
    if (httpRequest.readyState === 4) {
      if (httpRequest.status === 200) {
        //Should just return the json
        var response = JSON.parse(httpRequest.responseText);
        // console.log(response);
        return callback(response);
      } else {
        alert('There was a problem with the request.');
      }
    }
  } catch(e) {
    alert('Caught Exception: ' + e.description);
  }
}
httpRequest.open(type, url);
//httpRequest.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/xml');
httpRequest.send();
}
```

And heres how I am calling the function

```
makeRequest('//teamtreehouse.com/davidendersby.json', 'GET', function(treehouseData){
  console.log(treehouseData);
  sortedTreehousePoints = sortObject(treehouseData.points, 'DESC');
  getTotalPoints(treehouseData);
  getPoints();
  getTreehouseBadges(treehouseData);
});

//  //Not Working
 makeRequest('http://api.bf4stats.com/api/playerInfo?plat=xone&name=davetherave2010&output=json','POST', function(battlefieldData){
  console.log(battlefieldData);
});
```

Comment: if your doing a POST, why are you sending the parameters via query string?

Comment: Why are you not just using jQuery for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like httpRequest is being declared in the global namespace, . Use var. Like this:

```
function makeRequest(url, type, callback) {
type = typeof type !== 'undefined' ? type : 'GET';
var httpRequest;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // Mozilla, Safari, ...
   httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else if (window.ActiveXObject) { // IE
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't seem to find any problem except from [Best Practices](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_best_practices.asp)
And the fact that you get the response more than once.
[image: Chrome debug]
(Line 67 it's the `console.log(battlefieldData);` and Line 58 it's the `console.log(treehouseData);`)

I suggest you check your XAMPP or WAMP or Apache or whatever server you are using and also try [jQuery Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) and/or the shorthand methods [$.get()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) and [$.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

**EDIT**
Also there might be a problem with referential integrity as both requests are ASYNC. But i'm no so sure about this.

**EDIT 2**
By referential integrity i meant in the js environment, not in a database referential integrity way, maybe the link may be misleading.

Comment: what does referential integrity have to do with the requests being async?

Comment: If you reassign or change value to a variable while waiting for the response? He's not declaring variables you see. You know the difference between using `var` in js and not using it right?. But as i said before, i'm not so sure about that.

Comment: as far as I know 'referential integrity' is a db-related concept (it may apply to other things I'm unaware of, though I highly doubt). Regarding, the missing `var` before `httpRequest`: that will mess things up for sure since the `onreadystatechange` handler will use the same `httpRequest` variable

Comment: It appears there was a misunderstanding, I'll be glad to upvote your answer after you edit it and clarify what you meant by "referential integrity" to avoid further confusion (not everybody reads the comments).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all of you help. It was a scoping issue, Declaring the httpRequest variable inside the function fixes the issue.

I have some experience in jquery I'm trying to push my knowledge in pure javascript. Will definitely look into strict mode.